# How do I keep my apex:outputPanels separated?

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I'm trying to create a page for entering scores based on questions.  Each question has a score, some text, and another score.  Here is the relevant visualforce:

```
<!-- Scoring Page -->
    <apex:pageBlock title="Score Candidate" id="thirdPage" rendered="{!isThirdPage}">
        <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="QuestionTab" id="tabPanel">
            <apex:tab label="Video Interview Questions" name="questions" id="questionsTab">
                <!-- Question 1 -->
                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="Q1" styleClass="container">
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="Q1_Text" style="float:left;width:30%">
                        Question 1 Text
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="Q1_Responses" style="float:right;">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><apex:outputLabel value="Question Score" for="q1_score" /></td>
                                <td><apex:inputField value="{!questions[0].Value__c}" id="q1_score" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b><apex:outputText value="{!tls[0].Level_3__c}" /></b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><apex:outputLabel value="TLS Score" for="q1_tls" /></td>
                                <td><apex:inputField value="{!tls[0].Value__c}" id="q1_tls"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <!-- Question 2 -->
                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="Q2" styleClass="container">
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="Q2_Text" style="float:left;width:30%">
                        Question 2 Text
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="Q2_Responses" style="float:right;">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><apex:outputLabel value="Question Score" for="q2_score" /></td>
                                <td><apex:inputField value="{!questions[1].Value__c}" id="q2_score" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><b><apex:outputText value="{!tls[1].Level_3__c}" /></b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><apex:outputLabel value="TLS Score" for="q2_tls" /></td>
                                <td><apex:inputField value="{!tls[1].Value__c}" id="q2_tls"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Written Assignment Responses" name="written" id="writtenTab">
                Hey look written!
            </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

But the divs that apex:outputPanel generates keep overlapping like such:

[image: Clashing divs]

Ideally I want the questions to be one on top of the other, the way the visualforce implies it should be.  Any advice on this would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your table structure. What follows the first `<TR>` tag (row) will tell the browser how many columns to expect to create in each successive row based on the number of pairs of `<TD>  </TD>` tags it sees. It will allocate space in each row for them. You need to use `colspan="2"` inside of your `<TD>` tag if you combine two columns which appears to be what you're attempting to do.

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td><apex:outputLabel value="Question Score" for="q1_score" /></td>
         <td><apex:inputField value="{!questions[0].Value__c}" id="q1_score" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><b><apex:outputText value="{!tls[0].Level_3__c}" /></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td><apex:outputLabel value="TLS Score" for="q1_tls" /></td>
         <td><apex:inputField value="{!tls[0].Value__c}" id="q1_tls"/></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

The other thing I see is that you're using floats, which could also be part of what you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You're floating the inner div, so the outer div tags are effectively empty, causing the behavior you're seeing. See this code for an example:

```
<apex:page >
    <div style="border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid red">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid green">
        <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid blue">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

This is because floats do not participate in the parent element's box model.

Instead, simply make the inner div tags inline-blocks if that's your intent, and they will stack on each other properly because of the outer div tags.